# In search for a definition for some kind of an "integrating" vector field.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question, vector-analysis

I am searching for an expression with integrals or derivatives which let me take any vector field, and calculate a vector that is the **integral along the field** in some sense.

The result should be a vector pointing out the sink we end up in from the current coordinate.

**Simplest example**: One point sink and no sources: All vectors of our integral point to the universal sink.

**Second example:** Planetary bodies and gravity force. Each vector points to the mass center of the body which an object at rest in that point would end up hitting.

**Third example:** Ideal plate capacitor, two really close electrically opposite charged plates. Here I imagine the integral result should be the vector pointing to the point on the charged plate which a charge would hit if dropped from rest at point of origin.

---

**EDIT**

**Not explicitly stated before:** *length of travel* in some sense being equal to norm of vector.

**Fourth example: circular movement:** A rotation $\cases{{\bf v}_x = -k\pi y\\{\bf v}_y=k\pi x}$ should follow the field for "length" $k\pi$ (or less if field hits a sink). Any point on a circle would under this "integral" rotate $k\pi$ radians along the circumference of a circle of radius $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: Just curious: why do you need such function?

Comment: Yes. That was my thought: "if I had this, I wonder what could I build with it.".

Comment: Oh, okay. But you can quite safely assume this first, do the thought experiment with such function and then decide is it really useful. By the way, speaking of "simplest example": when people want to understand the structure of phase space, they numerically approximate attractor's basins. Just start the trajectory from the point, see where it goes and color it depending on at which attractor it came.

Comment: I know for sure it will be useful for some things, but I am also sure that saying those things will definitely limit the usefulness of my responses.

Comment: It sounds like what you want to know about is [streamlines (and related things)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streamlines,_streaklines,_and_pathlines)